# Problema React: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy utilizando una función en un componente en React, internamemnte esa función ejecuta un ciclo While para poder generar una serie de números aleatorios, solo que la función se ejecuta más de una vez y React para evitar el ciclo infinito me manda el error (Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.) Entiendo que probablemente tenga que ver con los renderizados pero no me queda claro. Adjunto imágenes del código.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto formateado segun corresponda (si es un error como comentario, si es codigo como codigo),siempre.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! No tiene nada que ver con tu ciclo while.. que elemento estas mostrando mas de una vez? o tenes un router?

Comment: @gbianchi muchas gracias por la recomendación, la voy a tomar en cuenta para mejorar mis preguntas. De hecho no estoy mostrando ningún elemento mas de una vez y tampoco un router, lo único que tengo es un h1 en ese componente, el componente donde uso la función del while es <Main />.

Comment: no.. para la proxima no, para esta ;) usa el boton [edit] y pone el codigo como texto.. si no, hay que tomarse el trabajo de transcribirlo.. y vos ya lo tenes como texto en tu compu...

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que esto sucede porque llamas el setter repetidamente, lo correcto sería obtener todos los valores y luego agregarlos al array. Considera también que `random` pertenece a un conjunto pequeño de números, o sea que cuando ya se hayan generado todos los valores posibles ocurrirá efectivamente un ciclo infinito.

```js
const masNumeros = []
while (valor) {
  const random = ...;
  // no está entre los valores anteriores ni entre los nuevos
  if (!numerosAleatorios.includes(random) && !masNumeros.includes(random)) {
    masNumeros.push(random);
    valor--;
  }
}

setNumerosAleatorios([...numerosAleatorios, ...masNumeros]);
```